# Not receiving worklight push notification in ios

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst

I am building a app for which , push notification is one of the important feature using worklight.
In android it is working fine. But in ios i am not receiving any notification. I have added my logs in this question .

I even tried replacing the jre\lib\security\cacerts file in JDK 7 with jre\lib\security\cacerts file in JDK 6 .But no luck ,it was not working . Sp please provide with some useful solution.

```
[19/11/14 14:49:28:403 UTC] 00000044 com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsFeedbackConnection             W Failed to retreive invalid devices
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: com.ibm.jsse2.util.j: End user tried to act as a CA
    at com.notnoop.apns.internal.Utilities.parseFeedbackStreamRaw(Utilities.java:209)
    at com.notnoop.apns.internal.Utilities.parseFeedbackStream(Utilities.java:219)
    at com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsFeedbackConnection.getInactiveDevicesImpl(ApnsFeedbackConnection.java:105)
    at com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsFeedbackConnection.getInactiveDevices(ApnsFeedbackConnection.java:74)
    at com.notnoop.apns.internal.AbstractApnsService.getInactiveDevices(AbstractApnsService.java:132)
    at com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsServiceImpl.getInactiveDevices(ApnsServiceImpl.java:36)
    at com.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.apns.ApplicationConnection.getInactiveDevices(ApplicationConnection.java:123)
    at com.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.apns.APNSMediator.maintain(APNSMediator.java:102)
    at com.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.Dispatcher.maintain(Dispatcher.java:93)
    at com.worklight.integration.notification.NotificationCleanupTask.step(NotificationCleanupTask.java:24)
    at com.worklight.core.tasks.TaskThread.run(TaskThread.java:120)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: com.ibm.jsse2.util.j: End user tried to act as a CA
    at com.ibm.jsse2.j.a(j.java:23)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.a(qc.java:190)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.ab.a(ab.java:239)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.ab.a(ab.java:136)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.bb.a(bb.java:93)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.bb.a(bb.java:230)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.ab.r(ab.java:270)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.ab.a(ab.java:259)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.a(qc.java:568)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.h(qc.java:759)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.a(qc.java:807)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.e.read(e.java:18)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.e.read(e.java:21)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:398)
    at com.notnoop.apns.internal.Utilities.parseFeedbackStreamRaw(Utilities.java:200)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: com.ibm.jsse2.util.j: End user tried to act as a CA
    at com.ibm.jsse2.util.i.a(i.java:11)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.util.i.a(i.java:116)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.util.i.b(i.java:95)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.util.g.a(g.java:17)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.yc.a(yc.java:73)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.yc.a(yc.java:110)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.yc.checkServerTrusted(yc.java:101)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.bb.a(bb.java:19)
    ... 20 more

[19/11/14 14:49:28:403 UTC] 00000044 com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsFeedbackConnection             E Couldn't get feedback connection
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: com.ibm.jsse2.util.j: End user tried to act as a CA
    at com.notnoop.apns.internal.Utilities.parseFeedbackStreamRaw(Utilities.java:209)
    at com.notnoop.apns.internal.Utilities.parseFeedbackStream(Utilities.java:219)
    at com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsFeedbackConnection.getInactiveDevicesImpl(ApnsFeedbackConnection.java:105)
    at com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsFeedbackConnection.getInactiveDevices(ApnsFeedbackConnection.java:74)
    at com.notnoop.apns.internal.AbstractApnsService.getInactiveDevices(AbstractApnsService.java:132)
    at com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsServiceImpl.getInactiveDevices(ApnsServiceImpl.java:36)
    at com.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.apns.ApplicationConnection.getInactiveDevices(ApplicationConnection.java:123)
    at com.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.apns.APNSMediator.maintain(APNSMediator.java:102)
    at com.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.Dispatcher.maintain(Dispatcher.java:93)
    at com.worklight.integration.notification.NotificationCleanupTask.step(NotificationCleanupTask.java:24)
    at com.worklight.core.tasks.TaskThread.run(TaskThread.java:120)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: com.ibm.jsse2.util.j: End user tried to act as a CA
    at com.ibm.jsse2.j.a(j.java:23)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.a(qc.java:190)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.ab.a(ab.java:239)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.ab.a(ab.java:136)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.bb.a(bb.java:93)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.bb.a(bb.java:230)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.ab.r(ab.java:270)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.ab.a(ab.java:259)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.a(qc.java:568)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.h(qc.java:759)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.qc.a(qc.java:807)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.e.read(e.java:18)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.e.read(e.java:21)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:398)
    at com.notnoop.apns.internal.Utilities.parseFeedbackStreamRaw(Utilities.java:200)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: com.ibm.jsse2.util.j: End user tried to act as a
```

Comment: Are you saying this question is resolved? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26653834/push-notification-is-not-received-in-worklight-6-2 --- provide there the solution please.

Comment: @IdanAdar yes in android.

Comment: Great, so please lets not keep that other question unresolved while dealing with this new issue.

Comment: @IdanAdar I deleted that question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the following [IBM tech note](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21456835), this error may occur if the Root CA certificate does not contain the BASIC CONSTRAINTS extension.

To resolve the issue:

> As per X509V3 specifications, any root CA certificate is supposed to
>   contain a BASIC CONSTRAINTS extension and the value of the CA flag
>   should be set as TRUE. Otherwise, the certificate is deemed to be an
>   end-entity certificate and not a CA certificate. During SSL handshake,
>   if a server certificate chain uses a root CA certificate that does not
>   have this extension set correctly, the handshake can fail at the
>   client end with the above mentioned error message. To resolve the
>   issue, contact the CA who issued the certificate and get the server
>   certificate chain corrected. Another potential workaround is to use
>   the IbmPKIX trustmanager instead of IbmX509 trustmanager at the client
>   end. The trustmanager is set in java.security file using the property
>   "ssl.TrustManagerFactory.algorithm"

See if the above is related to your issue.

Comment: how to check whether the CA flag is set to true.

Comment: where will the java.security file be found.

Comment: ssl.KeyManagerFactory.algorithm=IbmX509
ssl.TrustManagerFactory.algorithm=PKIX is the values i have in my server.

Comment: any suggestion for this issue.